# Stripe API: Get List of Payments Recevied in GBP

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

I am attempting to get a list of payments made to our Stripe account within a date period in GBP.

I am using the Stripe.Net nuget package.

When i call for a list of events and then filter down to charges i get the data i want but the charges are in the currency charged to the customer.

Is there a way to get a list of all payments/refunds within a time period in a single currency please?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Search API](https://stripe.com/docs/search) with the `created` and `currency` parameters to return the filtered data you need, with either Charges or Payment Intents objects.

```
var options = new ChargeSearchOptions { Query = "currency:'gbp' AND created>1620310503" };

var service = new ChargeService();
service.Search(options);
```

Comment: many thanks for the help. unfortunately, this only brings back payments that we made in GBP and ignores other payments received. i am trying to get all payments, in whatever currency paid, but converted to GBP. To tie back to the total shown on the stripe.com dashboard page

Comment: It's not immediately clear what it is you're actually trying to achieve but I imagine you'll need to look at the [Balance Transactions API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions) then. Those objects store the data relating to any [FX](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions/object#balance_transaction_object-exchange_rate) involved (i.e. if the presentment currency was `usd` but settled in your GBP Stripe balance) and are a reflection of any transaction within your Stripe account.